# Stop formatting portion of the code in Source Editor in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In visual Studio aspx editor, i want to stop portion of the code to be formatted on format using ctrl - K ctrl - D .

Problem faced.
       I am using two validator with text '*', both should be in same place i adjusted using css. But when format the code , this formatting introduce extra space.

If anybody knows the solution for this, please answer for it.

---

Expectation:

I am expecting a marker tag, to stop alignment.

For example,

<DontChange><asp:....>......</asp:....>
</DontChange>

When i give like this content between DontChange tag should not be aligned in Editor on every align.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent question. Does highlighting the code block and selecting Edit->Advanced->Format Selection (or press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F) work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Somehow VS would have to remove the extra tags when you build/deploy. I belive a simple <%-- --%> comment somehow should disable the formatting, but I haven't found anything yet :(

Perhaps an extension/plugin could do the trick?